# Flutter showDialog completes before the dialog is destroyed

Tags: flutter

I call `showDialog` to construct an `AlertDialog` that receives `TextEditingController`. I `await` for the dialog to close, and then I try to `dispose` the controller. But I get an exception:

```
A TextEditingController was used after being disposed.
```

Why is this happening? And how do I wait until the dialog is destroyed for sure?

My code:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => _onPressed(context),
          child: Text('Show'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onPressed(BuildContext context) async {
    final controller = TextEditingController();

    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => MyDialog(controller),
    );

    controller.dispose();
  }
}

class MyDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;

  MyDialog(this.controller);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: TextField(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My next attempt was to wrap `dispose()` into this:

```dart
SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  controller.dispose();
});
```

Still the error persists.

This error is not visible to the user and could be ignored. Also the controller is not that expensive to leave undisposed. Finally I can use `StatefulWidget` for the dialog content, create the controller there and dispose it in the widget's `dispose()`.

But I am mostly interested in the framework design that leads to this as my case is actually more elaborate.

So why is this happening? And how do I wait until the dialog is destroyed for sure?

Comment: I think this happens because an alert dialog can be opened many times afterwards and disposing controllers inside functions are not right way to do it. Controllers should be initialized in initState and should be destroyed in dispose before super.dispose(). As you know, controllers are not just normal variables so it is better don't treat them as variable in your code.

Comment: Do you mean there's no guarantee that a dialog's content is destroyed at all? If I convert `MyDialog` to a `StatefulWidget`, it does get `dispose`d. Yet this happens after `_onPressed` completes. It is called from `BuildOwner.finalizeTree` from `WidgetsBinding.drawFrame` from `SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback` from `handleDrawFrame`.

Comment: I think that is all about. Probably, if you close a dialog, the dialog itself is not completely destroyed unless you navigate to another stateful widget / stateless widget in navigator stack. If you really want to dispose a controller, try it with null value before disposing. `_controller = null` then `_controller.dispose()`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the controller is disposed of even the view is available.
**Improvement Suggestions**
You can create a single controller instead of multiple for memory efficiency.
For that, you need to clear the controller every time the dialog opens.
**Code to Change**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();// <= Add here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => _onPressed(context),
          child: Text('Show'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onPressed(BuildContext context) {
    controller.clear();                                     //<= Add here
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => MyDialog(controller),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The question was how to actually wait for the content to be destroyed. Also in your example MyHomePage should be stateful, otherwise the controller could be recreated at any time losing its text.

Comment: The controller within MyHomePage would be created only once but controller in MyDialog will be created every time dialog opens. I will suggest to make both as statefullWidgets and put dispose method in the override dispose method of that statefulWidgets.